# Почему в Debian не удаляются полностью пакеты и их зависимости?

Tags: debian

Решил я вот посмотреть разные окружения рабочего стола, поставил для начала KDE(установка рекомендаций в настройках aptitude выключено) (`aptitude install kde-plasma-desktop kwin-x11`), посмотрел и удалил (`aptitude purge kde-plasma-desktop kwin-x11`), а также выполнил `dpkg --purge $(dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1)` ибо конфиги почему-то не удалились, после этого вроде система вернулась в такое же состояние как и до установки(разве что в ~/ скрытые директории не удалились), начал ставить gnome (`aptitude install gnome`), посмотрел и таким же способом удалил (`aptitude purge gnome` и `dpkg --purge $(dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1)`
но при этом у меня осталось куча демонов каких-то работать и места на гигабайт меньше чем до установки, почему? и как можно сделать чтоб такого не было?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как советуют в [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce#Install_Xfce_in_an_already_installed_system), надо удалить пакеты, содержащие слово `gnome` в названии.

и там и у вас используются, как мне кажется, немного перегруженные конструкции. можно ведь использовать [поисковые термины](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.ru.html):

```
$ sudo aptitude purge '~ignome'
```

---

а чтобы полностью удалить (*purge*) информацию об удалённых пакетах (включая конфигурационные файлы), вместо:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge $(dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f 1)
```

гораздо элегантнее написать:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge '~c'
```

---

а по поводу «почему» надо смотреть на конкретную ситуацию: какие пакеты стояли у вас до эксперимента, какие были установлены/удалены во время эксперимента, какие остались установленным по окончании эксперимента, и исследовать зависимости, благодаря которым некоторые из установившихся по зависимостям пакетов не были удалены при удалении того пакета, благодаря которому они и были установлены.

---

например: стоит у вас какой-нибудь пакет `п1`, у него в зависимостях написано: `п2 | п3` (т.е., «п2 или п3»), и для удовлетворения этой зависимости установлен `п2`.

и вот вы для эксперимента устанавливаете пакет `п4`, у которого в зависимости написано: `п3`. соответственно, пакет `п3` будет установлен.

у вас получаются установленными четрые пакета: `п1`, `п2`, `п3` и `п4`.

наконец вы удаляете пакет `п4`, ожидая, что и пакет `п3` будет удалён: ведь он установился как зависимость вместе с `п4`.

однако ничуть не бывало: насколько я помню, пакет `п3` **не будет** удалён ввиду того, что он присутствует в числе зависимостей пакета `п1`.

---

и для того, чтобы внести «полную сумятицу в голове», вспомните, что пакеты связывают не только «просто зависимости», *depends* (которые могут быть и вариативными: «пакет1 или пакет2 или …»), но и *recommends*, *suggests* и *conflicts*. и при установке пакетов типа `gnome` (который, вообще-то, является мета-пакетом, т.е., просто набором зависимостей) по кросс-зависимостям могут быть установлены тысячи пакетов, образуя (вместе с пакетами, стоявшими до того) «адский» многосвязный граф, который, после удаления «стартового» пакета (`gnome`) может быть приведён к непротиворечивому состоянию сотнями (тысячами? миллионами?) разных способов, и лишь ровно один из этих способов «вернёт» вам в точности тот набор пакетов, который у вас был до установки «стартового».